# Getting interrupted exception when method called from two spring services

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

This is legacy code that i have to maintain. I am getting InterruptedException when this method is getting called from two spring services. The InterruptedException are sporadic and almost 1 in 10 cases fail because of this. Please highlight if someone can see any problem with the code.

```
private void openSocket() throws PrintingException {

        socket = new Socket();
        inetSocketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(ip, port);

        retries = 3;
        do {
            doRetry = false;
            try {
                socket.connect(inetSocketAddress, connectionTimeOut);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                throw new PrintingException("Error while trying to print on " + ip + ": " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                if (retries > 0) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(timeToWaitForRetry);
                    } **catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        throw new PrintingException("Error while trying to print on " + ip + ": " + ex.getMessage());
                    }**

                    doRetry = true;
                    retries--;
                } else {
                    if (socket != null) {
                        closeSocket();
                    }

                    throw new PrintingException("Error while trying to print on " + ip + ": " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        } while (doRetry);

        retries = 3;
        do {
            doRetry = false;
            try {
                socket.setSoTimeout(socketTimeOut);
            } catch (SocketException e) {
                if (retries > 0) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(timeToWaitForRetry);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        throw new PrintingException("Error while trying to print on " + ip + ": " + ex.getMessage());
                    }

                    doRetry = true;
                    retries--;
                } else {
                    closeSocket();
                    throw new PrintingException("Error while trying to print on " + ip + ": " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        } while (doRetry);
    }
```

I am getting interrupted exception in this code block :-

```
try {
       Thread.sleep(timeToWaitForRetry);
}catch (InterruptedException ex) {
       throw new PrintingException("Error while trying to print on " + ip + ": " + ex.getMessage());
}
```

stack trace :-

Error while trying to print on 10.26.9.102: sleep inter
rupted
de.component.backend.exception.PrintingException: Error while trying to print on 10.26.9.102: sleep interrupted
        at de.component.backend.domain.printer.Printer.openSocket(Printer.java:155)
        at de.component.backend.domain.printer.Printer.sendCommandsToPrinterWithResponse(Printer.java:100)
        at de.component.backend.domain.printer.zebra.ZebraPrinter.receivePrinterResolution(ZebraPrinter.java:169)
        at de.component.backend.domain.printer.zebra.ZebraPrinter.(ZebraPrinter.java:112)

Comment: You are interrupted when another thread interrupts your thread. Perhaps the call is too slow so some other thread in the application thinks it should be aborted? I would search for interrupt in the code and see if it is called from somewhere else! I don't envy you for maintaining that piece!

Comment: We have set timeout in HystrixCommand to 30 seconds and in this code block we are retrying 3 times but I have seen the configurations and 'timeToWaitForRetry' is 600 milliseconds. So it seems unlikely that  HystrixCommand is sending the interrupt to current thread. I haven't found any code with .interrupt() on current thread.

Comment: On the contrary it seems extremely likely. Perhaps with debug logging https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48952910/how-to-enable-hystrix-debug-level-logging you can see it happen?